# Recursive function or loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am trying to write a recursive function, but I am completely lost as to how to implement it. I currently have the following:

```
function change(p){
    // code for function
}

var c1 = change(start);
var c2 = change(c1);
var c3 = change(c2);
// etc. etc.
```

Is there any way to do this with a while loop? For example:

```
while(currentResultofFunction != goal)
    nestedly loop through as before until reaches true
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function change(p) {
    if (p != 1) { // your condition
        change(p);
    } else return p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
var val = start;
while(val) //or while val != goal
  val = change(val);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing, is *not* recursive. You maybe mean **iterative**.

You can loop through the variables in this way:

```
var n = 2;
for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
  if (i == 1) window['c1'] = change(start);
  else window['c' + i] = change(window['c' + (i - 1)]);
}
```